# Как грамотно сказать? И как верно расставить знаки?

Tags: орфоэпия

*Если потребуются какие-либо изменения в документации у вас есть наши контакты обращайтесь*

Answer (score 2):

Всё сказано грамотно - официальный стиль, - знаки же нужны следующие:

*Если потребуются какие-либо изменения в документации, у вас есть наши контакты - обращайтесь!*

Это моё предпочтение, но возможны варианты:

*Если потребуются какие-либо изменения в документации - у вас есть наши контакты: обращайтесь.*

*Если потребуются какие-либо изменения в документации, у вас есть наши контакты: обращайтесь.*

Comment: Галина, я бы сказал, что это смесь официального и разговорного, который стремится все сокращать: "если что нужно, у тебя мой телефон" или типа того. Нет?

Comment: Дорогой Ние, рада тебя видеть, - а пятёрка где? О_о Не-а, чистейший новоязный официоз.

Comment: Чем плох вариант "тире-запятая"? Если потребуются какие-либо изменения в документации - у вас есть наши контакты, обращайтесь.

Comment: М_Г, запятая перед "обращайтесь" хороша, я просто проглядела такой вариант; тире меня сомневает непадеццки... Нормальное ССП: главное - придаточное, запятая тут "классическая...

Answer (score 1):

**Если потребуются какие-либо изменения в документации, то у вас есть наши контакты. Обращайтесь, наши сотрудники всегда готовы оказть вам необходимую помощь!**

Да, здесь явное смешение стилей: информационно-деловое сообщение и выражение услужливой вежливости по отношению к клиенту, поэтому сообщение лучше разделить на два  отдельных предложения.